# How to count number of times a customer visited for EACH day in the search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query that searches for customers that have visted multiple times per day.  If I run this query for 1 specific day it works.  What I'd like to do is be able to query a range of dates.  For example I want to search 12/1/12 - 1/31/13 and have it check each day for multiple visits, and display the date that customer visited multiple times.  Below is my query that is not working:

```
SELECT        Customers.sBarcode, COUNT(Customers.sBarcode) AS [Number of Scans], Tickets.dtCreated
FROM            Tickets INNER JOIN
                         Customers ON Tickets.lCustomerID = Customers.lCustomerID
WHERE        (Tickets.dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-11 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-12 00:00:00', 102)) AND (Tickets.dblTotal <= 0)
GROUP BY Customers.sBarcode, Tickets.dtCreated
HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: How this is not working? Any errors? not the desired results??

Comment: Is `Tickets.dtCreated` date only, or does it include time as well as date?

Comment: Time as well.  It's not showing any results.  If I run the query 1 date at a time i get the results i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  Customers.sBarcode ,
        CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS dtCreatedDate ,
        COUNT(Customers.sBarcode) AS [Number of Scans]
FROM    Tickets
        INNER JOIN Customers ON Tickets.lCustomerID = Customers.lCustomerID
WHERE   ( Tickets.dtCreated BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-01 00:00:00', 102)
                            AND     CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-31 23:59:59', 102) )
        AND ( Tickets.dblTotal <= 0 )
GROUP BY Customers.sBarcode ,
        CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
HAVING  ( COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

Assuming you have time information your dtCreated field, the cast/floor/cast would drop it, then you can group on your date and expand your date range.

Comment: I would just add that the `CONVERT`s are doing nothing here and can be removed.

Comment: @Kevin: Note that a `Tickets.dtCreated` could conceivably have a value of 2013-01-31 23:59:59.9 .

Comment: True, a better option would be to either drop the times there as well, or use >= with the start date and < with the date after.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT      Customers.sBarcode, 
            COUNT(Customers.sBarcode) AS [Number of Scans], 
            convert(char(10),Tickets.dtCreated,102)
FROM        Tickets 
INNER JOIN  Customers ON Tickets.lCustomerID = Customers.lCustomerID
WHERE       Tickets.dtCreated >=CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-11 00:00:00', 102) AND 
            Tickets.dtCreated < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-18 00:00:00', 102) AND 
            Tickets.dblTotal <= 0
GROUP BY    Customers.sBarcode, convert(char(10),Tickets.dtCreated,102)
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1
```